# How are images stored in relation to the original post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 2 images that are associated with a post and can't figure out how Wordpress connects them to the post.

Here's the `wp_posts` table. The post has an `post_id=3378` and the two images are `post_id=3418` and `post_id=3918`.

[image]
I think it's through the `inherit` property but that key word isn't unique in this table. Sorry I'm new to WP, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are they associated in back, are they featured image or present in the wysiwyg?

Comment: thanks @vard, its neither. They are file uploads via ACF. Does that help?

Comment: Ah I see. Well then the relation is done inside wp_postmeta, if you look into that table you will see an entry with your page id as `post_id`, and as `meta_key` the name given in ACF. In `meta_value` you will probably find the ID of your media.

Comment: hmm, I have the post_id/ID of the media, the issue is associating it with the post_id/ID of the post

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you here. Isn't post_id / ID of the post the same thing or you mean something else?